# Rotate game-object from object-pool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'd like to rotate my bullet-object after it has been created (i.e. taken from the pool).

This is my function where the bullet is taken from the object pool and gets positioned respectively:

```
void CreateBullet (GameObject bulletObj, Transform _bulletPos, float xVal = 0f, float yVal = 0f) {

    //get bullet object from pool
    bulletObj = bulletPool.GetInstance (playerShotsGO);
    bulletObj.transform.position = _bulletPos.position;

    Vector2 pos = bulletPos.transform.position;//Position 0,0

    pos.x += xVal;
    pos.y += yVal;

    bulletObj.transform.position = pos;

    bulletObj.transform.SetParent (playerShotsGO.transform, true);
}
```

This is my update-function of my PlayerBullet-script where the bullet's position gets calculated:

```
void Update () {
    Vector2 position = transform.position;

    //compute the bullet's new position
    position = new Vector2 (position.x, position.y + speed * Time.deltaTime);

    //update the bullet's position
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Here my object gets instantiated:

```
protected virtual GameObject AllocateInstance (bool parent, GameObject parentObj) {
    GameObject instance = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate (prefab);
    if (parent) {
        instance.transform.SetParent(parentObj.transform, true);
    }

    instance.SetActive(false);
    pool.Add(instance);

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your object in your scene? Normally, you would create the GameObject, or set it to active, and then change your transform's rotation

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling from Unity3d's tutorials, you need to search the pool for an object that's ready to be used. If it's not found, you generate a new one. You then use `SetActive(true)` to show it, and set the rotation through `instance.transform.rotation = <Vector3>`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out!

Comment: Did this help you out @drpelz?

Comment: Uhm...not really. But I already figured it out. Thanks anyway.:)